# Reshaping a 3 dimensional array to 2 dimensions

Tags: matlab, matrix, multidimensional-array, reshape

I have a 3-dimensional matrix of dimensions: 427x470x48

I want to reshape this into a 2-dimensional matrix of dimensions: 48x200690

This would mean that old(1, 1, :) would correspond to new(:, 1)

Additionally, old(1,2,:) would correspond to new(:,2) and so on and so forth.

Thank You

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do:

```
new = reshape(permute(old, [3 2 1]), 48, []);
```

Also you can roughly check that they are equal by:

```
numel(intersect(old(1,1,:),new(:,1))) == 48;
```

Comment: This will not put the third dimension first as was requested.

Comment: Suggestions: a slight improvement would be `new = reshape(permute(old, [3 2 1]), 48, []);` . This `[]` computes the product of the other dimensions and assigns it to the last dimension of the `reshape`. Thus, as long as you want a `48xn` output, `n` will always be right.